# Возможно ли через nginx запустить сайт сделанный на reactjs так чтоб пользователи могли его использовать?

Tags: nginx, create-react-app

Возможно ли через nginx запустить сайт сделанный на reactjs так чтоб пользователи могли его использовать?

Answer (score 0):

Просто сделайте yarn build в папке с проектом и перекиньте содержимое папки build в корень сайт. Без разницы какой будет сервер Apache или Nginx. Вам даже node js на сервере не нужен ведь приложение уже построено.